# Problem with authors names in the references

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I'm having a problem in the references. When I have multiple names, I wrote all the names before compiling the file but that it selects randomly a few authors names by writing just the first letter of (first name and last name) as you can see below. I need help to show all the names completely.

### The bibliography section in the main file:

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{./references}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
```

### The reference input:

```
@TechReport{Evaluation,
author = {Aline Vieira de Mello, Luciano Copello Ost, Fernando Gehm Moraes, Ney Laert Vilar Calazans},
title = {Evaluation of Routing Algorithms on Mesh Based NoCs},
institution = {FACULDADE DE INFORMÁTICA},
year = {2004},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTtype = {•},
number = {40},
OPTaddress = {•},
month = {May},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
```

### The Output:

> [1] F. G. M. N. L. V. C. Aline Vieira de Mello, Luciano Copello Ost,
>   \Evaluation of                routing algorithms on mesh based nocs,"
>   FACULDADE DE INFORMTICA, Tech. Rep. 40, May 2004.

Thanks in advance,
Reagards.

Comment: Try to use `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: @Sigur `and` not `;`

Comment: after deleting the (comma) between the authors names and put instead (and), I got the first name completely but the last name still just the first letter. still I need both of them completely.

Comment: The style does `FUNCTION {default.name.format.string}{ "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" }` so first name should be abbreviated to a letter last name used in full.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Not a duplicate! Using the keyword `and` is only part of the job. The other part is to help BibTeX separate first names from composite surnames.

Comment: @Mico The solution to that is simply use a different style, the IEEE bst documentation explicitly says that function should _not_ be customised for any documents submitted to IEEE

Answer (score 1):

Using `and` rather than `,` as the keyword to separate authors is the first part. The second is to determine which parts of each name constitute first names and surnames.

If you write

```
author = {Aline Vieira de Mello and Luciano Copello Ost and Fernando Gehm Moraes 
          and Ney Laert Vilar Calazans},
```

BibTeX will parse each name as follows:

- First author: "Aline Viera" are the first names, "de" is the von component, and "Mello" is the surname;
- Second author: "Luciano Copello" are the first names and "Ost" is the surname;
- Third author: "Fernando Gehm" are the first names and "Moraes" is the surname;
- Fourth author: "Ney Laert Vilar" are the first names and "Calazans" is the surname.

I suspect, though, that the correct surnames actually are "Vieira de Mello", "Copello Ost", "Gehm Moraes", and "Vilar Calazans". If this is correct, you need to override BibTeX's parsing rules. Two approaches are available: the first inverts the order of first and last names and uses `,` as the symbol to separate the components, while the second uses curly braces to group the components of the surnames.

```
author = {Vieira de Mello, Aline and Copello Ost, Luciano and Gehm Moraes, Fernando  
          and Vilar Calazans, Ney Laert},
```

or

```
author = {Aline {Vieira de Mello} and Luciano {Copello Ost} and Fernando {Gehm Moraes} 
          and Ney Laert {Vilar Calazans}},
```

I recommend you use the first approach.

Note that under either approach the keyword, `and` is still used to separate authors.

Comment: Thanks @Mico for your answer, I tried your both approaches but they gave me the same result which is just the last name but the first name still abbreviated.

Comment: @whn13001 - The decision to abbreviate first and middle names is determined by the bibliography style you use. If you don't want abbreviated first names, don't use the `IEEEtran` style. Your code snippet, by the way, shows you loading two bibliography styles; however, only the first instruction prevails. If you want to use `unsrtnat`, don't load `IEEEtran` first.